# Extracting PDF's from EDGAR database

Tags: r, httr, edgar

Trying to extract the information from the PDF located here: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/784028/000078402823000002

However, even though this is an open API, it appears that the SEC blocks the extraction/scraping of the PDF (I get a 403 error when trying to use pdftools in R) and the associated .txt file appears to be encrypted.  Have tried using the XBRL and EDGAR package in R, but since this company doesn't publish the data via XML, those appear not to work.  Open to Python solutions as well.

Here is what I have tried:

```
library(httr)
library(XBRL)
library(edgar)
library(pdftools)

pdf_Academy <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/784028/000078402823000002/2022public.pdf"
academyInfo <- pdftools::pdf_info(pdf_Academy) 
academytxt <- pdftools::pdf_text(pdf_Academy)

df0 = httr::GET("https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK784028.json")

df1 = edgar::getFilings(cik.no = "784028",filing.year = 2022, downl.permit = "y", form.type = "ALL")
```

Comment: This has been noted in python forums (since I did some searching). The resolution with R packages is not clear. The revised requirements of Edgar are that the user-agent needs to be something that the server does not interpret as a scraping effort. Your question is really two part since the last two command proceeded without error and the only 403 error was the call to `pdf_info`. You should have indicated where in the code ( that you appear to have copied from someplace) the error occurred and the full text of the error and you should NOT submit multipart questions.